# Ability to change Ideas community assignment and default community?

Tags: administration, ideas

Does anyone have some experience in managing ideas? I like the feature, and am now getting some adoption, but users are not putting ideas in the right community or not using communities at all. Is there any way for an admin to go back in and change the community assignment? And also is there a way to setup the default community that is immediately available, once a person clicks on the ideas tab? Or should I maybe delete all other categories, will this then force the current ideas to be assigned to the only remaining community?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way for an admin to go back in and change the community assignment?

Unfortunately, it is not possible to reassign an Idea's Community. This is a [feature worth voting on](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpaKAAS).

Even if one tries changing the associated Community via the API, it throws `FATAL_ERROR System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: Idea.CommunityId` :-(

> Is there a way to setup the default community?

The display of Communities is according to their sort order. By adding a numeric prefix to their names:

```
1. Default Community
2. Internal Community
3. External Community
```

you can control which one appears first. Sorta.